# How to pass parameter value from view to Ext.window?

Tags: extjs

I am get confused to pass value from view to window,

I have a view contain the user info and one button on which click a new window opens to upload an Image file. the image upload code I done in window. But I want to pass User Id with the image which I want to post on server. the user Id I on View. I want to carry that userId on file upload window. How can I do this?

Bellow is my code.
file upload view

```
Ext.define('vDemo.view.FileUpload', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    region: 'center',
    border:'false',

    initComponent: function () {


        var me = this;
        this.form = new Ext.form.Panel({

            xtype: 'panel',
            border: false,
            //layout: 'vbox',
            padding: '2 2 2 2',
            bodyPadding: 10,
            frame: false,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'filefield',
                name: 'photo',
                fieldLabel: 'Photo',
                labelWidth: 50,
                msgTarget: 'side',
                allowBlank: false,
                anchor: '100%',
                buttonText: 'Select Photo...'
            }],

            buttons: [{
                text: 'Upload',
                handler: function () {
                    var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                    if (form.isValid()) {
                        form.submit({
                            url: 'photo-upload.php',
                            waitMsg: 'Uploading your photo...',
                            success: function (fp, o) {
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your photo "' + o.result.file + '" has been uploaded.');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }]
        });

        this.items = [this.form];
        this.callParent();


    }
});
```

UserForm view (on which button click I am open the file upload window)

```
Ext.define('vDemo.view.userHome', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    border: false,
    Padding: '5 5 5 5',
    title: 'Home',


    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;

        this.changingImage = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
            src:'', //'appRes/ProfilePic/ProfilePic1.png',
             width: 150,
              height: 170
        });

        this.image = new Ext.Container({
            cls: 'img-block',
            padding:'0 0 2 0',
            items: [this.changingImage]
        });

        this.ImagePanel = new Ext.form.Panel({
            padding: '5 5 5 5',
            layout: 'vbox',
            border: false,
            items: [
            this.image,
                           {
                               xtype: 'button',
                               text: 'Chage Image',
                               width: 150,
                               height: 30,
                               handler: function () {
                                   me.fileUpload();
                               }
                           }
                               ]

        });

        this.InfoPanel = new Ext.form.Panel({
            padding: '5 5 5 5',
            layout: 'vbox',
            border: false,

            items: [{
                xtype: 'hidden',
                name: 'hfUserAutoId'
            },
                           {
                               xtype: 'displayfield',
                               fieldLabel: 'Name:',
                               name: 'lblName',
                               value: ''
                           },
                           {
                               xtype: 'displayfield',
                               fieldLabel: 'Email:',
                               name: 'lblEmail',
                               value: ''
                           },
                           {
                               xtype: 'displayfield',
                               fieldLabel: 'Date of Birth:',
                               name: 'lblDateOfBirth',
                               value: ''
                           },
                           {
                               xtype: 'displayfield',
                               fieldLabel: 'UserId',
                               name: 'lblUserId',
                               value: ''
                           },
                           {
                               xtype: 'displayfield',
                               fieldLabel: 'Gender',
                               name: 'lblGender',
                               value: ''
                           },
                           {
                               xtype: 'displayfield',
                               fieldLabel: 'Blood Group',
                               name: 'lblBloodGroup',
                               value: ''
                           },
                           {
                               xtype: 'displayfield',
                               fieldLabel: 'Hieght',
                               name: 'lblHieght',
                               value: ''
                           }]

        });

        this.form = new Ext.form.Panel({

            padding: '10 100 10 100',
            layout: 'hbox',
            header: {
                titlePosition: 0,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Back',

                    handler: function () {
                        me.fireEvent('getBack');
                    }
                }]
            },

            items: [me.ImagePanel, this.InfoPanel]

        });


        this.items = [this.form];
        this.callParent();
    },

    fillForm: function(sRec) {
        var me = this;
        console.log(sRec);
        // var sRec1 = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('UserInfo').getById(ssRec.get('userAutoId'));

        console.log(sRec[0].userAutoId);
        me.form.getForm().findField('hfUserAutoId').setValue(sRec.userAutoId);
        me.form.getForm().findField('lblName').setValue(sRec[0].firstName + " " + sRec[0].lastName);
        me.form.getForm().findField('lblUserId').setValue(sRec[0].userid);
        me.form.getForm().findField('lblEmail').setValue(sRec[0].email);

        if (sRec[0].gender == true) {
            me.form.getForm().findField('lblGender').setValue("Male");
        }
        else if (sRec[0].gender == false) {
            me.form.getForm().findField('gender').setValue("Female");
        };

        me.form.getForm().findField('lblDateOfBirth').setValue(sRec[0].DOB);
        me.form.getForm().findField('lblBloodGroup').setValue(sRec[0].bloodGroup);
        me.form.getForm().findField('lblHieght').setValue(sRec[0].hieght);
        // me.form.getForm().findField('image').setSrc(sRec.get('profilePicPath'));
        me.changingImage.setSrc(sRec[0].profilePicPath);
    },

    fileUpload: function () {

        this.uploadWinPanel = new vDemo.view.FileUpload({});
        var hfUserAutoId = me.form.getForm().findField('hfUserAutoId').getValue();

        this.EditWin = new Ext.Window({
            //header:false,
            Height: 400,
            width: 320,
            title: 'Upload Photo',
            border: 0,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            modal: false,
            items: [this.uploadWinPanel]
        }).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you pass the user id on initialization of the *uploadWinPanel* like so:

```
  var hfUserAutoId = me.form.getForm().findField('hfUserAutoId').getValue();
  this.uploadWinPanel = new vDemo.view.FileUpload({
    userId: hfUserAutoId
  });
```

And then in the FileUpload component, beside the *filefield*, you add a *hiddenfield* which grabs the userId value:

```
    items: [{
        xtype: 'filefield',
        name: 'photo',
        fieldLabel: 'Photo',
        labelWidth: 50,
        msgTarget: 'side',
        allowBlank: false,
        anchor: '100%',
        buttonText: 'Select Photo...'
    },{
        xtype: 'hiddenfield',
        name: 'user_id',
        value: this.userId
    }]
```